# How can I stop 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' in an L1 Regression Project?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, logistic-regression

I'm getting an error code:
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
from the below code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
#colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'gray', 'indigo', 'orange']
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow']
weights, params = [], []

for c in np.arange(-4, 6, 1): 
    lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1.0, solver='lbfgs', multi_class='auto', random_state=0)
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    weights.append(lr.coef_[1]) 
    params.append(1*c)
    weights = np.array(weights)

for column, color in zip(range(weights.shape[1]), colors):plt.plot(params, weights[:, column], label=df.columns[column + 1], color=color)
plt.axhline(0, color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=3)
plt.xlim([xx1.min, xx1.max])
plt.ylabel('weight coefficient')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.38, 1.03), ncol=1, fancybox=True)
plt.show()
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use np.ndaray instead of numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at the end of the first iteration (c = -4), you append to `weights` which is a list, but at the end of the iteration, you convert `weights` to an `np.array` using `weights = np.array(weights)`, which does not have an `append` method.

You can solve this by using from the beginning `np.array`, and use the following syntax:

```py
weights, params = np.array([]), np.array([])

for c in np.arange(-4, 6, 1): 
    lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1.0, solver='lbfgs', multi_class='auto', random_state=0)
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    weights = np.append(weights, lr.coef_[1])
    params = np.append(params, 1*c)
```